# Como criar componente transparente e tangível - Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Estou querendo criar um `Panel` que ficará sempre com a propriedade `BringToFront`, capaz de ser totalmente transparente a ponto de mostrar componentes atrás dele e ainda sim ser possível clicar nele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
.

Valeu pela ajuda! :)

Comment: Olá TsPlayerT,  já experimentou mudar a cor do Panel para Transparent?

Comment: Sim, já tentei mas só deixa visível a cor de fundo do componente de trás que no caso foi o próprio Form :/

Answer (score 1):

Para deixar o Painel transparente ajuste a propriedade `panel1.BackColor` com o método [`Color.FromArgb`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.8) onde o argumento alpha regula o grau de transparência,

Exemplo:

```
// Para uma cor sólida alpha deve ser 255
// Para completa transparência alpha deve ser 0
// Nesse caso alpha é 25
panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(25, Color.Blue);
```

Quanto ao controle por cima dos outros a propriedade [`TopMost`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=netframework-4.8) só exite para [`Forms`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=netframework-4.8). O que dá para fazer é usar o método [`Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex(Control, Int32)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_SetChildIndex_System_Windows_Forms_Control_System_Int32_) com um número bem elevado com relação aos outros controles pois mesmo que crie ou modifique seus controles irmãos  eles sempre ficarão abaixo dele.

Exemplo:

```
// Enquanto o child index dos outros componentes ficam entre 0 e 10 panel1 
//tem child index 10000 o que garante sempre estar por cima 
form1.setChildIndex(panel1, 10000);
```

Comment: Eu troquei a coloração do componente usando essa propriedade, BackColor mas mesmo assim ele só deixa transparente para cores, não mostra a `Label`.

Agora, enquanto a sobreposição do componente. Eu coloquei um override em `OnControlAdded()` com `panel1.BringToFront()`